# Fibonacci function with C

Tags: c, function, integer, switch-statement, fibonacci

I want to calculate the i-th sentence of the *Fibonacci* sequence:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int fibo(int i);

int main()
{
    return 0;
}

int fibo(int i)
{
    switch (i)
    {
    case 1:
        return 0;
        break;
    case 2:
        return 1;
        break;
    default:
        int a = 0, b = 1;
        for (int p = 3; p <= i; p++)
        {
            b += a;
            a = b - a;
        }
        return b;
        break;
    }
}
```

But it has an error for 18 line for `int a = 0, b = 1;` as this:

```
10.c: In function 'fibo':
10.c:18:9: error: a label can only be part of a statement and a declaration is not a statement
   18 |         int a = 0, b = 1;
      |         ^~~
```

I use VS Code for IDE.

Comment: The error message is precisely correct. Case labels are labels.

Comment: Maybe this is helpfull for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46341364/label-can-only-be-used-as-part-of-a-statement-error

Comment: regarding: `int main()
{
    return 0;
}`  This fails to call the function: `fibo()`  so that function will never be executed

Comment: the variable `i` is never set, never declared, (this should be done in `main()` so the code will not compile.

Comment: note: the Fibonacci sequence starts with 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8,...  The posted code does not implement that sequence

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in C, in a `switch` statement, in a `case`, to have a local variable, the body of the `case` must be enclosed in braces '{' and '}'

Answer (score 0):

```
  #include <stdio.h>
    int fibo(int i);
    int main()
    {
        return 0;
    }
    int fibo(int i)
    {
        int a = 0, b = 1;
        switch (i)
        {
        case 1:
            return a;
            break;
        case 2:
            return b;
            break;
        default:
            for (int p = 3; p <= i; p++)
            {
                b += a;
                a = b - a;
            }
            return b;
            break;
        }
    }
```

Here I used the declaration part outside the switch case as inside the label only statements are allowed not declaration.

Answer (score 0):

The C grammar does not allow a declaration to be labelled. `default:` and `case <expr>:` are labels. There are 3 ways to fix the problem in your code:

- move the declarations outside of the body of the `switch` statement:

  ```
  int fibo(int i) {
      int a, b;
      switch (i) {
      case 1:
          return 0;
      case 2:
          return 1;
      default:
          a = 0, b = 1;
          for (int p = 3; p <= i; p++) {
              b += a;
              a = b - a;
          }
          return b;
      }
  }
  ```
- enclose declarations in a block:

  ```
  int fibo(int i) {
      switch (i) {
      case 1:
          return 0;
      case 2:
          return 1;
      default: {
              int a = 0, b = 1;
              for (int p = 3; p <= i; p++) {
                  b += a;
                  a = b - a;
              }
              return b;
          }
      }
  }
  ```
- add a null statement after the label:

  ```
  int fibo(int i) {
      switch (i) {
      case 1:
          return 0;
      case 2:
          return 1;
      default:;  // this is a null statement
          int a = 0, b = 1;
          for (int p = 3; p <= i; p++) {
              b += a;
              a = b - a;
          }
          return b;
      }
  }
  ```

Note also these remarks:

- the `break;` statements in your `fibo` function are never reached and should be removed,
- the `case 2:` is redundant: the `default:` code would produce the same result,
- your code does not implement the classic Fibonacci sequence: `1 1 2 3`... instead it produces `0 1 1 2`... You should change the tests to this:

  ```
  int fibo(int i) {
      switch (i) {
      case 0:
          return 0;
      default:;  // this is a null statement
          int a = 1, b = 1;
          for (int p = 2; p < i; p++) {
              b += a;
              a = b - a;
          }
          return b;
      }
  }
  ```
- you should probably return `0` for negative numbers too. Just simplify the code as:

  ```
  int fibo(int i) {
      int a = 1, b = 0;
      while (i-- > 0) {
          b += a;
          a = b - a;
      }
      return b;
  }
  ```